# Building wheel package with a CPython built from sources on Windows

Tags: python, pip, cpython, python-wheel

I'm building Python 3.12 from sources on Windows through the scipt `PCbuild\build.bat -p x64`.
The result gets built in the `amd64` folder and `python.exe` works perfectly fine.

My problem comes when I try to `pip install` a package that gets compiled with `msbuild`, such package as `cs_Oracle`. It fails when trying to locate `python312.lib`. That file exists in `PCbuild\amd64`, but that path is not given to the linker as `/LIBPATH:` argument.

I created a `libs` folder in the `cpython` root directory (where I cloned the repo) and copied `_tkinter.lib`, `python3.lib` and `python312.lib`. I got the idea from looking inside my Python 3.11 install that I got from the official installer.

And it worked! The wheel compiling that failed earlier succeeded (`cx_Oracle` now works with Python 3.12).

My question: is there a way I can bundle the built CPython like the installer would? So that I have a same structure as an official Windows Python release.